# Magento 2.1 Rest API save attribute group does not change attribute_set_id

Tags: magento-2.1, rest-api, attribute-set, attribute-group

#### Preconditions

1. Magento 2.1.7
2. PHP 7.0.18

#### Steps to reproduce

1. Having a test attribute group:

```
{
  "attribute_group_id": "103",
  "attribute_group_name": "Test",
  "attribute_set_id": 4,
  "extension_attributes": []
}
```

2. Send a Rest API request:

> PUT /rest/V1/products/attribute-sets/4/groups

Headers:

```
content-type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer <authorization token>
```

Body:

```
{
  "group": {
    "attribute_group_id": "103",
    "attribute_group_name": "Test",
    "attribute_set_id": 13,
    "extension_attributes": []
  }
}
```

#### Expected result

```
{
  "attribute_group_id": "103",
  "attribute_group_name": "Test",
  "attribute_set_id": 13,
  "extension_attributes": []
}
```

#### Actual result

```
{
  "attribute_group_id": "103",
  "attribute_group_name": "Test",
  "attribute_set_id": 4,
  "extension_attributes": []
}
```

Response 200 OK.

Works if changing "attribute_group_name".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acknowledged as a bug. Link to the [issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9921) on GitHub.